# Cannot install kernel core

Tags: linux

I am trying to upgrade my CenOS from 7 to 8. Refer to https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/ I find errors when doing step 5

Step 5: Install the New Kernel Core for CentOS 8 To install a new kernel for CentOS 8, run the command.

```
# dnf -y install kernel-core
```

Here is my situation.

```
[root@localhost ~]# dnf -y install kernel-core 
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00 
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00 
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'baseos', ignoring this repo. 
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'appstream', ignoring this repo. 
Last metadata expiration check: 1:22:03 ago on Wednesday, August 09, 2023 PM03:30:00 HKT. 
No match for argument: kernel-core Error: Unable to find a match: kernel-core
```

How to fix this? I cant find any solution about it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed the two lines saying `Failed to synchronize cache for repo '[...]', ignoring this repo.`? That's a good indicator as to why it can't find `kernel-core` or any package for that matter.